# Select element from table Where something in Select

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have this query

```
SELECT
    equipe_id
FROM
    user
GROUP BY
    equipe_id
HAVING
    COUNT(*) >= 5
```

and it returns 1 and 3.

I want to use this next query using the previous query

```
SELECT
    name,
    location
FROM
    equipe
WHERE
    equipe_id IN ??? previous query result (1,3) ???
```

I hope that makes sense. Thank you

Comment: You got it... just switch those `???` over to `(` and `)` respectively and stick that other query in there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT name
     , location 
  FROM equipe 
 WHERE equipe_id in (SELECT equipe_id FROM user GROUP BY equipe_id HAVING COUNT(*) >= 5);
```

Comment: It's not exactly rocket science, this.

Answer (score 5):

We can also try doing this via joining to a subquery:

```
SELECT e1.name, e1.location
FROM equipe e1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT equipe_id
    FROM user
    GROUP BY equipe_id
    HAVING COUNT(*) >= 5
) e2
    ON e1.equipe_id = e2.equipe_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, this can be done also without the inner subquery, like this:

```
SELECT
    e.name,
    e.location
FROM
    equipe AS e
INNER JOIN
    user AS u ON u.equipe_id = e.equipe_id
GROUP BY
    e.equipe_id, e.name, e.location
HAVING
    COUNT(*) >= 5
```

Comment: Note that ANY_VALUE is version specific. Also, are you sure that both queries are equivalent?

Comment: Thanks for feedback, made some changes.